# Bind plugin command to Build System?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I am trying to do a build system with advanced commands.

My build command needed project specific settings, so as I didn't found how to load a project setting in a build command, I wrote a plugin to generate my command, but for now I am only able to access such command through the command palette or using a custom menu field.

Is there a way to use a plugin command in a build system action ?

Comment: why not bind your plugin to a key combination?

Comment: I did that, but in addition I would like to have a clean Build System